# How to avoid hash-collision when elements are known

Tags: hash, hashtable

Is there anyway to avoid the hash-collision in hash function, if we know the size of the input before building the hash table?
In other words, how can we make the worst-case insertion in O(1) time?

Comment: Do you know the *size* of the input, or the actual items?

Comment: @AmiTavory Let's say I know everything about the input - size, each item's information....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is known as a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). There are many known algorithms for this (see [this article in Dr. Dobbs'](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/generating-perfect-hash-functions/184404506) on one such algorithm). Most of them rely on some randomized parameterized scheme that has a nontrivial chance of finding no collisions. Once such a parameter is found, you have a perfect hash. See [this lecture](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect1004.pdf) for a readable intro.